# Create Lists with Different Types

Tags: lis, adapt

inish the code that creates the areas list. Build the list so that the list first contains the name of each room as a string and then its area. In other words, add the strings "hallway", "kitchen" and "bedroom" at the appropriate locations.
Print areas again; is the printout more informative this time?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dv1f.png)

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, ant an screenshot.